Precision issue in R: Why does dividing by 0.00001 in the operation 1/0.00001 cause problems, while other magnitudes do not?
When trying to run a simulation experiment with the following code, I found that the results returned had issues. Why is this happening?
> length(rnorm(100000))
[1] 100000
> length(rnorm(1/0.00001))
[1] 99999

I tried other magnitudes, and there were no problems.
The bigger:
> length(rnorm(1000000))
[1] 1000000
> length(rnorm(1/0.000001))
[1] 1000000

Furthermore, I tried using the high-precision computation package Rmpfr to observe numerical precision, and the results are as follows:
> mpfr(1/0.0001,precBits = 53)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  53   bits 
[1] 10000
> mpfr(1/0.00001,precBits = 53)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  53   bits 
[1] 99999.999999999985
> mpfr(1/0.000001,precBits = 53)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  53   bits 
[1] 1000000
> mpfr(1/0.0000001,precBits = 53)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  53   bits 
[1] 10000000

Why does the precision issue only occur when dividing by 0.00001?

I am not sure how familiar you are with floating point arithmetic in computers, but in general computers struggle to represent floating point numbers and division accurately. If you are doing something related to that, you should consider the possible error. Mainly, a==b in your program changes to something like |a-b|<0.0001 and other comparisons also get affected in a similar fashion.

As the previous comment alludes, you have likely found yourself in the First Circle of the R Inferno. In other words, not every numeric value can be represented in a binary system. Functions such as all.equal() are designed precisely for managing issues like this that arise from floating point arithmetic.

This free online calculator allows you to compare the numeric value that your computer shows you versus what the computer 'sees'.
